# How can I get my homepage to be displayed in my SERP instead of inner pages?

Tags: seo, search-results, canonical-url

I have a website with couple of pages.

In the home page I have fair amount of content with required amount of keyword density. Other pages are fine and having enough amount of content whereas contact page is just a simple page with no content except a contact form.

When I search for my domain name in Google Search, on the third page I'm ranked `26, 27, 28`, and the pages are:

```
mydomain/contact
mydomain/someservice
mydomain/someservice2
```

Whereas I am more interested to find my domain name alone in a Google search instead of inner pages; moreover I don't want to see that weird *contact* page appearing instead of my homepage.

If I use `<link rel="canonical" href="http://homepage.com/" />` for all the rest pages will that help me?

Comment: Does it showing your main domain only when you search in google like site:www.yourdomain.com

Comment: @HelpingHands - Yes, when I search in that way, first result is my main domain and second result in my contact page.

Comment: then in normal search also your main domain should be there in later pages I think.

Comment: Does this answer help clarify things for you?? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76719/why-in-the-search-results-of-google-does-not-appear-the-unique-name-of-my-websit/76723#76723

Answer (score 1):

No, using `rel=canonical` in this way will not help you. If anything, search engines would probably penalize you because a canonical link is meant to point to the source of duplicate content. Since the pages on your site are not duplicates of the home page, using `rel=canonical` would be incorrect. See the Google webmaster support site article on [using canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en), and some useful tips from the [Google webmaster central blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html?m=1).

If such visitors to your site absolutely must go to the home page, one solution would be to redirect them based on the  fact that they were referred from a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you need to do is get some links to your home page from other sites.  You are ranked in the twenties now for your URL because you don't have enough reputation.   It doesn't take many external links for Google to start recognizing your home page as the proper navigational result for searches for your domain name.

Once your homepage has a few links, it with automatically outrank your inner pages for branded searches.   You still want your inner pages to rank for when somebody searches for something like "contact *brand*" or "service1 *brand*".

Some places that you can start with for links:

- Other websites that you own
- Friends and with websites, blogs, or personal homepages
- Business directories
- Your local town's website or local chamber of commerce
- A facebook page and other social media