# How can I get my site to show up in Google for the keywords of its brand name (not all as one word)

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, google-ranking

Let us assume I have a website name www.mynewwebsite.com

When I open Google and search for "**mynewwebsite**", it lists me the website at top. But when i search for "**my new website**" with spaces in between I could not even see it even after ten pages of listing.

What should I do to make it work? I know that the answer is related to SEO. But is it a really big process for me to make this happen or can this be done easily?

Comment: How much competition is there for "my new website" keywords?   Are the things that are ranking at the top now all big brands that have pages or sections of their site about it?

Comment: Do you use the phrase "my new website" on your site currently?   If so, where?

Comment: Simply because search terms exist within a domain name does not ensure your site will be found for those terms. Your site has to rank for those terms.

Comment: This answer explains what you are asking. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76719/why-doesnt-searching-for-the-unique-name-of-my-website-bring-the-site-up-in-a-t/76723#76723

Answer (score 1):

First time you need to do Search Engine Optimization. Please follow blows steps:

1. Make sure you follow Google Webmaster Guideline.
2. Make sure your website has done properly On-page SEO (URL, Title, H1-H6 Tags, Content, Images, Alt tag, Anchor tags, Internal link etc.).
3. Off-Page SEO (Search Engine Submission, Local Citation, Directory Submission, Social Book Marking, Web 2, Online PR, Article Submission, Q & A, Forum Posting etc.
4. Continue provide Organic Content for targeted visitors.
5. Make Social Media Profile & share content at there.

Answer (score 0):

Getting your site to rank for your brand name is one of the easiest SEO tasks.   A good brand name isn't used as a phrase much already.   Assuming you have chosen something fairly unique, Google will start ranking your site for variations of it soon. To make it happen:

1. Put the phrase verbatim on your site.
2. Wait a few months
3. Follow some advice from [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I had this exact problem on one of my sites.   I put "MyBrand" as the alt text on the logo and used "Copyright My Brand" in the footer.   It wasn't long before Google was ranking the site for both search terms.

Comment: The OPs question is not about branding, but rather, not ranking for the individual terms within the domain name. This is a simple matter of misunderstanding. The OP has an unrealistic expectation. I explain this in the link in my comment. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm assuming that they bought a domain that matches their brand name.  It would be silly to do otherwise.

Comment: I am going on this part of the question... *But when i search for "my new website" with spaces in between...*

Comment: It isn't unreasonable to want to rank for people who type in the multiple words of your brand name / domain name with spaces.

Comment: I did not say it was unreasonable, just not realistic. For example, awesomeredcorvette.com and awesome red Corvette will perform completely differently and it is not realistic that the domain name awesomeredcorvette.com will automatically compete for the highly competitive awesome red Corvette. The two are completely different searches. Cheers!!

Comment: True, but "awesomeredcorvette.com" would be an awful domain name and brand name.   Don't choose that!  Choose "bigdavescorvetteshopwilmington.com" instead.  ;-)

Comment: Agreed. The OP is not telling us his domain name. It could be awesomeredcorvette.com. ;-) We don't know. It could be bestseoexpert.com. It is about matching expectation and realistic results. It could also be masterwebpro.exchangestack.com.

Answer (score 0):

- Apply the name in the meta title, for example: `<head><title>my new website</title></head>` . Read more: **[Search Console Help of Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)** + **[**article MOZ Title Tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)**** + **[check SERP via simulator](http://www.seomofo.com/snippet-optimizer.html)** .
- Apply the elements of H as a structure. For example: mark each page of your website with the content of the H1 element as "my new website" (probably this you can set in the logo of your website). Next, use the descending structure of the children of this element as h2, h3, h4 etc. Please note that the number of these elements indicates the importance of the marked text / content of the web page. Read more: **[HTML Headings of W3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)** + **[HTML/Elements/h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 of W3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/h1,_h2,_h3,_h4,_h5,_and_h6)** + **[HTML5: Edition for Web Authors of W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/)** + **[HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)** with filter selection "outline" + check your structure via [**HTML 5 Outliner**](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/). 
  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm impatient so I only skimmed the answers above (and they seem totally valid).

If the website in question is yours (you're not a 3rd party like a marketing agency) then this will be easy:

--Set up a Google+ page (or "My Business" or whatever they are calling it now...and fill out all the details).

--Do whatever is needed to verify your business (phone call, mailed postcard, etc.).

--Verify the domain in Google Search Console / Webmaster Tools.

--Running a few branded AdWords ads couldn't hurt either.

Do any/all of those things and I bet Google pays more attention to you for those terms.

If it has an RSS feed, you'd be wise to submit it to Feedburner as well (an often overlooked Google service)...and, as others mentioned, make sure the site uses that exact phrase/name in it's content,